# Сортировка по дате Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Имеется представление, которое выводит на страницу определенные записи по ключу(в данном случае категории) . Они то выводятся хорошо, но как еще добавить такую настройку, что бы выводило сразу новые записи, а не старые?

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
    #Домашняя страница
    cat = Category.objects.all()
    posts = News.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    q = Category.objects.get(id=1)
    id1 = News.objects.filter(category = q)[:4]
    q = Category.objects.get(id=2)
    id2 = News.objects.filter(category = q)[:4]
    q = Category.objects.get(id=3)
    id3 = News.objects.filter(category = q)[:4]
    context = {'posts' : posts, 'cat':cat, 'id1' : id1, 'id2' : id2, 'id3' : id3}
    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
<ul>
        {% for post in id1 %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'posts:post_full' post.id %}">{{post.name_news}}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял, вам нужно использовать order_by() для модели News, поскольку именно из этой модели вы хотите показывать последние записи.

```
id1 = News.objects.filter(category = q).order_by('-date_added')[:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить во вью в `urlpatterns` что-то вроде:

```
(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=News.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:4],
                                template_name="News/posts.html"))
```

И потом, через `Jinja` организовать цикл в HTML документе:

```
        {% for post in object_list %}
            <li>
                <a>{{post.name_news}}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Включите в эту логику отбор по категориям и все получится + сокращение кол-ва кода.